# Can we access the value of a variable from any part of the program in python?

Tags: python, variables

Is it possible to get the value of name from anywhere in the program?

For ex:

```
reply = f'Nice shades, {name}'
print(reply)

name = input("Enter your name: ").title()
```

While using functions, we use 'global', what can one do to run this program?

Comment: Move the last line up to be the first line.

Comment: Python executes instructions *in order*. You can’t tell it to use a variable which is defined a few steps later. Independently of `global` scope considerations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a variable before you define it. To run your program you can write this first

```
name = input("Enter your name: ").title()
```

and then the rest of your code.